# How to override error message in @hapi/joi?

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, validation, joi

I am trying to override custom error message in `Joi`.

let's say i have a schema like follow.

```
const joiSchema = Joi.object({
  name: Joi.string().required(), 
  email: Joi.string().email().required()
})
try{
    const schema = joiSchema.validateAsync(req.body);
}catch(error){
    error.details.map((detail) => {
        // customize error message
    });
}
```

I need to send error message like follow.

```
{ errors: { name: "Name is Required.", email: "Email is Required." } }
```

How to get `fieldName` like `name` in `details` array in `Validation Error`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround like below.

```
const errors = [];
err.details.forEach((detail) => {
  const currentMessage = detail.message;
  detail.path.forEach((value) => {
    errors.push({ [value]: currentMessage });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just get the error and process like it

---

```
catch(error){
     var data = data.details;
     var message = data[0].message;  // you can get other fields also like this
     var json={"status":"0","message":message,"data":{}}; // you can customize your json response
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Following approach too help

```
    const errorList = [...errors];
    errors.forEach((error, index) => {
        const tmpError = { ...error };
        tmpError.message = "Your custom error message";
        errorList[index] = tmpError;
    });
    return errorList;
```